# OpenSilver 'Tapped' event not triggered on phone

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, opensilver

I have a website made using OpenSilver (it's the new SilverLight, it's a framework that converts c# wpf code into web pages).

If I put on a TextBlock the WPF event 'Tapped', like this :

```xml
<TextBlock Text="Se connecter" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50"
           Tapped="label_login_title_Tapped" />
```

```cs
private void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

The event is triggered when :

- I click on the textblock on my PC
- I click on the textblock on my phone with 'Computer' mode activated in Chrome

But it doesn't trigger without 'computer' mode enabled.

**How/what event to use to detect a touch and a click on an element of my page ?**

Comment: Tapped is not an event in WPF, but in UWP and WinUI. Perhaps update the question tags.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `Tapped` event does not work properly on mobile devices. Please use `MouseLeftButtonDown` event instead.

As OpenSilver is opensource framework, feel free to fix issues and make PRs.